# Trying to convert a mention from a users command into a member type

Tags: discord.js

I am currently trying to make a command that allows the user to enter a command then mention a user to then timeout said mentioned user. But the timeout function requires a guild member data type. Still new at this and have been very confused please help. Thanks!

[Here is the code of the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f1nK.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't upload code, results or data as images for these reasons: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get a member from mention use this code:

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first()
```